# Synchronise 2 scrollviewers silverlight

Tags: silverlight, scrollviewer

I want to synchronize 2 scrollviewers. Please let me know how to get scroll event of both scrollviewers and then synchronize them both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First get the 2 scrollbars of the scrollviewers you want to sync.
In this case, `scrollviewer1` and `scrollviewer2`
Then we get event handlers of both the scrollbars, in this case vertical. Then we can easily sync them through the events. The `ScrollToVerticalOffset` will scroll as per the other one does.

```
        ScrollBar vertical1 = ((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(scrollviewer1, 0)).FindName("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;
        vertical1.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(vertical1_ValueChanged);

        ScrollBar vertical2 = ((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(scrollviewer2, 0)).FindName("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;
        vertical2.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(vertical2_ValueChanged);


    void vertical1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        scrollviewer2.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue);
    }

    void vertical2_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        scrollviewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(e.NewValue);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it will work, just rename the scrollviewers with the ones you are using. I personally have used this code

Comment: I've tried to use that, but VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(scrollviewer1, 0) returns an error, I've tried VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(scrollviewer1) and it returns 0.