# Syncronize 2 Scrollviewers in Silverlight

Tags: xaml, silverlight

I have some elements in my Silverlight app, distributed in a `Grid`, like that:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|              | Columns Header (A)                  |
------------------------------------------------------
| Rows Headers | Content Panel (C)                   |
| (B)          |                                     |
|              |                                     |
|              |                                     |
|              |                                     |
------------------------------------------------------
```

In (A) I'll have some headers for the columns, and in (B) some headers for the rows that will be presented in the content area.

In (C) I'll have my main content.

What I'm trying to achieve is a fixed header, so when the user scroll the Content Panel (C), it will automatically scroll the headers to keep them aligned. I tried to use the solution indicated in this answer : [Synchronise 2 scrollviewers silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849524/synchronise-2-scrollviewers-silverlight), but the line below gives me an error:

```
ScrollBar vertical1 = 
  ((FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(scrollviewer1, 0))
        .FindName("VerticalScrollBar") as ScrollBar;
```

The error is on the `GetChild` Command, which returns `null`.

How can I achieve that?

I thought about using a Scrollbar instead of a `ScrollViewer`, but I don't know how to use that. My content `Panel` consists of a `StackPanel`. Should I put a `ScrollBar` inside the `StackPanel`?

Comment: To be clear, does the `GetChild` actually return a value but the cast fails or cast succeeds and the `as Scrollbar` code returns a null value due to it not being a scrollbar?

Comment: Why are you trying to recreate a DataGrid?

Comment: Having trouble visualizing the end result goal you have. Any chance you have a visual example of what you're after?

Comment: I'm trying to make my headers fixed, to always be on screen when i scroll the content. But I'm thinking about what @Nkosi said, maybe I'm taking the wrong approach to it. I'll try to do it with DataGrid.

Comment: I'm trying to use a DataGrid, but it brought another doubt. I posted it in a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374132/silverlight-make-a-column-bound-to-a-array-item-editable