# Silverlight make a column bound to a array item editable

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

I have a `DataGrid` in my Silverlight application, which is bound to an array of objects. Since the columns will be variable, I bound each of them to an array item:

My object:

```
public class TravelTimeItem
{        
    public string From { get; set; }
    public int[] Times { get; set; }
}
```

I build my grid with that:

```
grdTravelTime.Columns.Clear();

grdTravelTime.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { 
    Binding = new Binding("From")                
});

for (int i=0; i < amountOfColumns; i++)
    grdTravelTime.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() 
    { 
        Binding = new Binding("Times[" + i.ToString() + "]"),
        Header = (i + 1).ToString()
    });

grdTravelTime.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
grdTravelTime.IsReadOnly = false;
grdTravelTime.ItemsSource = GetItems();
```

The code above is working, I can see all array values displayed correctly in the grid, but I need the values to be editable. The "From" column, bound to a simple STring property, is editable, but the others, bound to a array item, is not.

How can I make this columns editable? Is there other option to bound this columns, taking into account the amount of columns can be different each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make this columns editable?

You need to replace `int` with a custom type that has a property with a public setter:

```
public class TravelTimeItem
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public YourType[] Times { get; set; }
}

public class YourType
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
...
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfColumns; i++)
    grdTravelTime.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
    {
        Binding = new Binding("Times[" + i.ToString() + "].Value"),
        Header = (i + 1).ToString()
    });
```